# See if link text wraps onto 2 lines with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the CSS and HTML below. I have a menu where the lis are a set height and width and have position relative. The links within them are positioned absolutely to take up all the available space so that the entire li is clickable. So far so good.

The issue is that the amount to link text may vary. When the link text wraps onto 2 lines (eg the 2nd link) I want there to be less vertical padding. I would add a class to the 2nd link for this except that the solution needs to be dynamic and with javascript. The menu may change so that the first link has more text and wraps onto 2 lines, in which case I would need to remove its vertical padding too. I need this to happen without needing to change the code.

I started to look into a solution with jQuery. I tried measuring the height of the link so if it was above 'x' then I could add class which removed the vertical padding. However this wont work as the height is set by absolute positioning.

Is there another way to measure if the text is wrapping onto 2 lines? I could count the number of characters but this doenst seem that reliable as some characters take up more width than others.

Would it work if I added a span within the link that contained the text? Then presumably the link could still be positioned absolutely and its span could have its height measured?

http://jsfiddle.net/cUQbJ/3/

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Link1</a>    
</li>    
<li>
    <a href="#">Link 2 with long text</a>    
</li>    
<li>
    <a href="#">Link3</a>    
</li>    



 li {
   display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 83px;
    min-height: 53px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
a {
    padding-top: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

UPDATE - I need to support IE7.

Comment: So you *basically* need your content to be vertically-align: middle to look nice?

Comment: Yes, is there a css only solution?

Comment: But I also need the link to but the full height and width of the li so the full li is clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using jQuery to insert a span around the link text. Then jQuery measures the height of the span and apply padding to its li if required.

This probably isnt the best solution from a responsive point of view and if users resize the browser but its working for me and this is only a styling issue so not the end of the world if it goes a bit wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any JS here.

Lets modify HTML structure slightly. I wrapped link content in `span`. We will vertically align these spans instead of `a` tags.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="valign"><span class="valigned">Link 2 with long text</span></a>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cUQbJ/5/

I abstracted main CSS which makes the trick into two separate classes `.valign` (for parent) and `.valigned` (what needs to be centered).

Comment: Im afraid the solution doesn't work in IE7 which I need to support.